# Minimize code in Contiki-OS

Tags: msp430, contiki

When compiling the example codes from the Contiki port [Thingsquare Mist](http://thingsquare.com/mist/) for the MSP430 on the [EXP430 board](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/MSP-EXP430F5438_Experimenter_Board) I get

```
/usr/lib/gcc/msp430/4.5.3/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: hello-world.exp5438 section `.text' will not fit in region `rom' 
/usr/lib/gcc/msp430/4.5.3/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: section .vectors loaded at [0000ff80,0000ffff] overlaps section .text loaded at [00005c00,000106df] 
/usr/lib/gcc/msp430/4.5.3/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: region `rom' overflowed by 2090 bytes collect2: ld returned 1 exit status 
rm hello-world.co obj_exp5438/contiki-exp5438-main.o Process returned error code 2 make: *** [hello-world.exp5438] Error 1
```

This also happens with the `blink` example, with even more bytes overflowed. How can I set optimization or removed unused components so that I can get started with the basic examples?

Answer (score 2):

Typically the configuration for a platform is done in:

```
contiki/platform/econotag/contiki-conf.h
```

(replace econotag with whatever your TARGET is)

There are a lot of settings there that you can enable or disable.

As for the specific configuration to make you examples work... I don't know as I don't have any experience with that platform. (or much experience with Mist).